# java JPA - call sql function using restriction api

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I need to call sql function by using restrctions API.
tried following code but fails

```
...
Criterion criterion = Restrictions.gt("SQRT(POW(a.column1-b.column1,2))/1609", 90);
criteria.add(criterion);
...
```

got following exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: SQRT(POW(...
```

**Note** 
I can't use sqlRestriction method due to usage of other table alias.
Also doesn't want to use native query.

Comment: can you show the getCriterion method?

Comment: @TridevChaudhary forget about that, see updated question.